# n-dimensional simplex $\Delta^n$: every cycle without boundary is a boundary

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplex

This question is concerned with the evaluation of the homology groups $H_k(\Delta^n)=H_k(\Delta^n,\mathbb Z)$, where $\Delta ^n$ is a $n$-dimensional simplex. Since $\Delta^n$ is retractable, $H_k(\Delta^n)=\{0\}$ for all $k$.

Now, let's try to evaluate $H_k(\Delta^n)$ directly by simplicial structure on $\Delta^n$. Indeed, all subsimplexes of $\Delta^n$ forms a simplicial structure of $\Delta^n$. Let $C_n$ denote the free abelian group with generators being the simplexes in this simplicial structure. We then have the boundary operators $\partial_n$ defined in the usual way. We expect the homologies $H_k(\Delta^n)=\ker \partial_k/\text{Im}\partial _{k+1}$ to be trivial, **so we want to show that all $k$-dimensional subcomplexes without boundary are the boundary of some $(k+1)$-dimensional subcomplex.**

The fact written in **bold** doesn't seem to be very obvious to prove geometrically and directly from the property of simplexes. Is there any way to show that $\ker \partial_k=\text{Im}\partial _{k+1}$ by considering the simplicial structure? Can one compute $H_k(\Delta^n)$ directly by simplicial structure on $\Delta^n$?

In other words, the result written in bold sounds pretty non-trivial for me and it is not obvious to prove without referring to the homotopy invariance of $H_n$ and a few other theorems. **I want to know if it has an easy and elementary proof.**

Comment: By $H_k (\Delta ^n)$ you mean simplicial homology right? Not singular homology?

Comment: @NoelLundström simplicial and singular homology groups are isomorphic, so they are the same thing as far as I know. Sorry if I am not clear. Of course, here I am computing the simplicial homologies.

Answer (score 3):

One may calculate this directly.

The k-simplices of $\Delta^n$ are given by $(k+1)$-element subsets of $\{0, \cdots, n\}$. The boundary operator is given by $$\partial \{i_0, \cdots, i_k\} = \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j \{i_0, \cdots, \hat i_j, \cdots, i_k\},$$ where the hat denotes "drop this variable".

Consider the operation $f(S) = \{0\} \cup S$ when $0 \not \in S$ and $f(S) = 0$ when $0 \in S$. Geometrically, we are taking the "cone towards 0"; every $k$-simplex that already contains 0 is "coned again" and doesn't contribute any $(k+1)$-simplices (because the cone is contains in the k-simplex itself); that's why we set $f(S) = 0$ in those cases.

I claim that $fd + df = 1$. In particular, if $c$ is a cycle, this says that $c = f(d(c)) + d(f(c)) = d(f(c))$, so that $c$ is a boundary.

Now we simply need to check this term-by-term.

First, suppose $0 \in S$. Then we have $f(S) = 0$, and hence $df(S) = 0$. At the same time, $$d(\{0, i_1, \cdots, i_k\}) = \{i_1, \cdots, i_k\} + \sum_{j=1}^k (-1)^j \{0,i_1, \cdots, \hat i_j, \cdots, i_k\},$$ so that $$f(d(\{0, i_1, \cdots, i_k\})) = \{0, i_1, \cdots, i_k\}.$$ Thus for basis elements $S$ with $0 \in S$ we see that $fd + df = 1$.

Now suppose $0 \not \in S$; that is, $S = \{i_0, \cdots, i_k\}$ where $i_0 > 0$. Then

$$f(d(S)) = \sum_{j =0}^k (-1)^j \{0, i_0, \cdots, \hat i_j, \cdots, i_k\},$$ while $$d(f(S)) = S + \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{j+1} \{0, i_0, \cdots, \hat i_j, \cdots, i_k\}.$$

In particular we have that almost all terms of $(df+fd)(S)$ cancel out; we are left with $(df+fd)(S) = S$. Thus we have checked that $df + fd = 1$ on basis elements, so it is true for every chain, and as above we have this constructed a chain $f(c)$ so that for every cycle $c$, we have $d(f(c)) = c$.

Comment: The notation $\{ ... \}$ is wrong. What you actually do is you take ordered subsets and mod out by orientation to obtain your chain complex of k-simplices. Not subsets.